# Does an interior point necessarily pass through the boundary under a homotopy?

Tags: gn.general-topology

It's a straightforward exercise to show that if a point moves continuously from the inside of a set to the outside, it necessarily passes through the topological boundary of the set. This question is about what happens if the point stays fixed and the set moves under a homotopy.

To make this precise, let $M$ be a contractible manifold (without boundary). Let $K\subseteq M$ be compact. Let $x_0\in K$. Let $F\colon [0,1]\times M\rightarrow M$ be a homotopy such that $F(0,\cdot)$ is identity, and $x_0\notin F(1,K)$. Does there exist $t$ such that $x_0\in F(t,\partial K)$, where $\partial K$ is the topological boundary of $K$?

What makes this difficult is I am interested in the image of the boundary, not the boundary of the image. Perhaps another way of phrasing this problem is: If we remove the point $x_0$, does $\partial K$ necessarily become non-nullhomotopic?

Comment: i think the proof should be to show that the sets of $t$ such that $x_0\in F(t,\int K)$, and such that $x_0\notin F(T,K)$ are both open. On the other hand, i don't know how to show this even if $F$ is an isotopy, and $K$ is a disk on the plane (kind of approximate Jordan theorem).

Comment: @erz I'm a bit skeptical about $I := \{ t \mid x_0 \in F(t,\mathrm{int} K) \}$ being open in general. Let for example $K = D_1 \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ and $x_0 = 0$. If I am not mistaken one gets $I = [0,1/2]$ by letting $F$ contract $D_1$ onto the origin up to time $t = 1/2$, and then moving the point away.

Comment: @LeoMoos i think in this case, $I$ also contains all the time when your concentrated point is within the open disk (by $D_1$ you mean the disk, right?)