# Approximate Jordan-Brouwer theorem (corrected)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

My first [attempt](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393128/approximate-jordan-brouwer-theorem/393134#393134) to ask this question sort of failed (I'll explain below).

This came up when thinking about this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393090/does-an-interior-point-necessarily-pass-through-the-boundary-under-a-homotopy).

It is well-known that the image of a homeomorphic embedding $f:S^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ separates the space into exactly two components, one of which is bounded, and another is unbounded. I am interested in "continuity" of this separation with respect to $f$, in the following sense:

Let $x$ be a point in the **bounded** (in my previous attempt I chose unbounded, naively thinking that this is the same problem) component. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be much smaller than the distance from $x$ to $f(S^n)$. Let $g:S^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be such that $\|g(s)-f(s)\|<\varepsilon$, for every $s\in S^n$. It is clear that $x\notin g(S^n)$. If $g$ is a homeomorphism, $g(S^n)$ also separates the space into a bounded an unbounded components, and so $x$ is in one of them.

> Is $x$ in the bounded component?

In fact, is the assumption that $g$ is a homeomorphism needed? Without we don't know how many components are there, but it is not unreasonable to expect that $g(S^n)$ still separates the space, and $x$ is in **a** bounded component.

Piotr Hajlasz's answer to the original question shows that if $y\in S^{n+1}$ is fixed, and $x$ and $f$ are such that $x$ and $y$ are connected in $S^{n+1}\backslash f(S^n)$, then $x$ and $y$ are connected in $S^{n+1}\backslash g(S^n)$ if $g$ is close enough to $f$. However, as far as I can see this does not imply the answer to the present question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be the generator of $H_n(S^n)$.  It is given that $f_*(u)\neq 0$ in $H_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{x\})$.  The assumptions ensure that the straight line from $f(p)$ to $g(p)$ never passes through $x$, so $g$ is homotopic to $f$ as a map $S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{x\}$, so $g_*(u)=f_*(u)\neq 0$, so $x$ is in the bounded component of the complement of $g(S^n)$.